# TextBox string to ListBox from first character to last

Tags: string, vb.net, winforms, textbox, listbox

I cannot figure out how to take a string from a `TextBox`, lets say "Hello!"
and when you press a button I would like the first letter, then second letter, third and so on to add to the `ListBox`.

In `TextBox` example:

Hello!

In `ListBox` example:

H

e

l

l

o

!

Comment: That's a rather broad question.  Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am having trouble separating each individual character so that I can add it to the listbox. In the example above if someone types hello then a button is pressed i would like to pull out each character of the string and add it to a listbox.

Comment: You do know how to get the string from the textbox. Yes? So, here is a secrete, a string is just an array of Char. You can get individual letters with a For Each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Linq's [Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) method and [ListBox.DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource) you can have a one liner:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = TextBox1.Text.Select(Function(c) c).ToList()
```

or, as in glm9637 answer:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a Look at the String.ToCharArray method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

So you would want to do something like this:

```
Sub ButtonPress()
    Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim inputArray() = input.ToCharArray()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(inputArray)
End Sub
```

Comment: there is an error because it is not a Listbox.ObjectCollection

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was to set up something like this where you set a string var as the textbox string, set that string as an array in another var, then for each item in that array add it to your listbox.

Dim input As String

```
    input = TextBox2.Text.ToString

    Dim inputarray = input.ToArray

    For Each obj As Object In input
        ListBox2.Items.Add(obj)
    Next
```